# Display Block only on users profile2

Tags: views, users, 7

I am using vies3, profile2 and context to display the users created content on their profile2 page. Using context i can allow the block to be display on the users drupal profile, how can i extend this to only show the block on the users profile2 profile?

Comment: do you have a sperate url for users profile2 profile?

Answer (score 0):

You want to display a unique block for each user that can be publicly seen right?

Use [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) to put a block into a field instead of using Context.

Or, use Contextual filters in views to use the users UID, but that's more complicated and I'm not sure how to do that since I used Display suite. I found something that might help here [Views and contextual filter as user id from url](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65324/views-and-contextual-filter-as-user-id-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

We've found ourselves in the need of exactly that and we've created a Profile2 context module, it's in github but I'll post it shortly in drupal.org

https://github.com/Ymbra/profile2_context