# Views and contextual filter as user id from url

Tags: 7, users, views

I want to create some views that shows the content created by the user, content flagged by the user and so on. I also need that when user a views user b then user a can see the content created by user b and so on. So i though i under Contextual filter i passed a default values as User Id from url. However when i visit the page i just see the view heading and no content.Please Help

Regards

Comment: just to be clear i dont want the logged in user but the user being viewed hence user id should be passed from url i guess

Answer (score 4):

Create a new Views view with Format, Fields, and Filter criteria configured as needed.

Then do the following:

1. Under `Advanced`, add a new `Contextual filter` for `Content:
   Author uid`.
2. Choose `Provide default value` and select `User ID
   from URL`.
3. Under `Page settings`, set `Path` to `user/%/myview`.

Now when you navigate to `user/1/myview` you should see content from user 1.

For Flags you need to add a relationship for the flag and filter by it. I believe [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/20155/5612) would help with that.

Comment: hi..well it works but if a assign this page as a call back to a quciktab instance as user/%/myview...then it shows nothing

Comment: hi...i figured it out..i passed it as a view and gave it an argument

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Entity Views Attachment (EVA)](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) module: it lets you add user entity data into the view. Here is an excerpt about it from the module's project page:

> ... provides a Views display plugin that allows the output of a View to be attached to the content of any Drupal entity. The body of a node or comment, the profile of a user account, or the listing page for a Taxonomy term are all examples of entity content.
>
> The placement of the view in the entity's content can be reordered on the "Field Display" administration page for that entity, like other fields added using the Field UI module.

Answer (score 0):

fields:
Content: Title
Content: Body

Path:/articles/%/page

Advanced: contextual filters
Content: Authored by

author

this configuration will print all nodes created by user 1 : /articles/1/page