# Get User ID from a Profile Page to use in a View

Tags: views, users

I'm creating Views blocks on profile pages such as drupalsite.com/users/testuser. I need to display blocks such as "Test User's Posts" and "Test User's comments." What is the best way to get the User ID of the profile pages' subject in order to filter the content based on this User ID?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `/user/testuser` is just an alias of `/user/n` where n is the user ID.  Which means the user ID is available in the unaliased URL, allowing you [to do this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/65336/27783).